# Chain UIViewControllers push and pop animation with UINavigationController dismiss / present modal view?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have View Controller with a (navigation controller) that can flip between 2 views (list and map), the user can switch between views. The map is the modal view. Currently I have done this using

When the user selects a location it will go down a hierarchy and present some location details.  In this hierarchy the user still has the option to view the map.  I am currently taking the user back to the root controller using the UINavigationController method **- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated** with animated being YES, if I immediately call the UIViewController method **- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated** it does both animations together, looking a little messy.

As it stands I decided to add a short NSTimer to delay the - (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated being called.

My question, is there a cleaner way of doing this?  A similar example I suppose is if you're using the App Store application and you've downloaded a new app.  The app store exists then animates to the last page of apps (assuming you're not there already), I'm looking for this style of animation.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track but you can skip the step of using the NSTimer by using
`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

```
...
   [self performSelector:showModalController withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
...

-(void)showModalController
{
   [self presentModalViewController:myModalViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Ah that looks a bit cleaner, seems like the only way to do this is with a timer, I wanted to avoid it as it might be some slight performance differences between devices.